# Вывод float, double без экспоненты

Tags: c++

Выводит float в виде -2.13323e+007. Как заставить нормально выводить - обычной дробью через cout?

Comment: Вообще странно, что он выводит с экспонентой, обычно цифры, которые не влезают отбрасываются... возможно, это зависит от компилятора, я использую visual studio и с таким не сталкивался.

Comment: то есть надо вид типа числитель на знаменатель ?!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот так:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << 221414252135125453453245325234.0 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float f = что-нибуть;
char str[32];

sprintf(str, " %3.10f ", f);
cout << str << endl;
```

Некрасиво, зато думать не надо :)

Comment: Мне всегда *printf казались удобнее, чем cout :-) Кроме нюанса, что в cout проще выводить целые классы (перегрузка/дружба).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float d;
    cout<<"Введите вещественное число: ";
    cin>>d;

    cout.setf(ios_base::fixed); //задаёт формат вывода

    cout<<d;

    return(0);
}
```

Вот, почитай на эту тему: http://savardge.narod.ru/cpp/article_cpp_t9.html

Answer (score 0):

```
cout.precision(n);
```

где n - число, обозначающее минимальную степень десятки, которая будет выводиться в экспоненциальном формате.

Т.е., при n=5 выводим 100000 как 1*10е5, а 99999 - не изменяя.

Однако при значениях n, близких к количеству знаков в целой части числа, дробная выводиться не будет, это стоит учитывать и брать n с запасом.

Comment: Это чем-то лучше чем `std::fixed`?

Answer (score -1):

Если память не подводит, переменной не хватает диапазона значений.
Используйте спецификатор long.