# Как вывести большое число в привычном формате?

Tags: c++, вывод, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Как можно написать код на c++ так чтобы при выводе N^2 при N=72 выводило не 4.72237e+021 а  4722366482869645213696

Comment: Неудивительно, что Вы над этим застряли. Учитывая, что 72 в квадрате это 5184.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод float, double без экспоненты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/10767/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-float-double-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b)

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о значении 2<sup>72</sup>, то оно представимо точно в плавающей двоичной арифметике вроде IEEE 754. Хватит даже 32-битного плавающего типа. Если ваша платформа построена на такой арифметике и реализует ее качественно, то вам просто нужно выполнить вычисление в плавающем типе и вывести результат в формате `fixed`

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
  float x = std::pow(2.0f, 72.0f);
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << x << std::endl;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d97961ea4de0df0b

---

При желании не составит труда просто в лоб реализовать длинное целочисленное вычисление и перевод обратно в десятичную запись, как делалось для этой задачи: [Сумма цифр числа 100!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916591/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-100) . Например, на базе второго подхода из моего ответа

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c63bb623f4605835

Хотя решать эту задачу путем циклического умножения на 2 - огромное расточительство.

Answer (score 1):

Вывести-то можно, только вот все цифры точными не будут...
Например,

```
unsigned long long v = 43697122555ull;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double x = v;
    x = x*x;
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << x << endl;
}
```

выведет (VC++ 2017)

```
1.90944e+21
1909438519586689646592
```

в то время как верное значение -

```
1909438519586689728025
```

Так что особого смысла в таком выводе не вижу. Ну не даст `double` нужной точности...

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, показанное число = это 2^72 (два в семьдесят второй степени), а не наоборот.

Во-вторых, размер такого числа, которое занимает 72 бита, превышает размер доступных примитивных целочисленных типов - 64 бита, поэтому для вычислений с абсолютной точностью (т.е. не с double) и для отображения понадобится библиотека для работы с длинной арифметикой, например, GMP *(сейчас браузер ругается на их сайт как фишинговый)* или MPIR.

Если нужны только несложные операции - сложение, умножение - то можно сделать самому, и на SO есть примеры ([случайный свежий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916591/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-100/916647#916647))